# What happens if strncpy copies random data into a buffer?

Tags: c++

Suppose you have a `char` buffer that you want to copy an `std::string` into. Are there consequences of copying extra data into the buffer, outside of the strings scope, even though the buffer has adequate size?

Example

```
std::string my_string = "hello";
char my_buffer[128];
memset(my_buffer, 0, 128);

strncpy(my_buffer, my_string.c_str(), 128);
```

So "hello" gets copied into `my_buffer`, but so will 123 other bytes of data that comes after `my_string`. Are there any consequences of this? Is it harmful for the buffer to hold this other data?

Comment: strncpy takes a string as argument?

Comment: That won't compile...

Comment: *Are there consequences of copying too much data into the buffer, even though the buffer has adequate size?* -- what? Is it too much or not?

Comment: You should read [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy). Pay close attention to the fine print, and then pretend that `strncpy()` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Shawn, from your link, it states, *"If, after copying the terminating null character from src, count is not reached, additional null characters are written to dest until the total of count characters have been written."* --> That means `my_buffer` would be written in with `my_string` and everything after that in `my_buffer` would be filled with NULLs. Do I understand it right?

Comment: Yes. But it's the behavior when the source is longer than the destination that's the real troublesome one. The function is meant for filling in fixed length char arrays that don't need to be 0 terminated, not reliably copying into a C style string that does. In C++, you should be using std::string instead of C strings anyways. In C, it's just too error prone and easy to overlook the edge cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but so will 123 other bytes of data that comes after `my_string`

This assumption is incorrect: `strncpy` pays attention to null termination of the source string, never reading past null terminator. The remaining data will be set to `'\0'` characters:

> destination is padded with zeros until a total of num characters have been written to it. [*[reference]*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy)

This is in contrast to `memcpy`, which requires both the source and the destination to be of sufficient size in order to avoid undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

OK, let's assume what you wanted is:

```
strncpy(my_buffer, my_string.c_str(), 128);
```

Thsi is always a 0-terminated string by definition, so considering:

> Copies at most count characters of the character array pointed to by src (including the terminating null character, but not any of the characters that follow the null character) to character array pointed to by dest.

You won't get anything copied after `"hello"` from the original string, the rest will be `0`s:

> If, after copying the terminating null character from src, count is not reached, additional null characters are written to dest until the total of count characters have been written.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean definitely copying that data, as your current code would end at a null terminator.

Essentially, no. Whatever data is in there will be used only as string data so unless you then tried to do something weird with that spare data (try to put a function pointer to it and execute it etc.) then it's basically safe.

The issue is with initially copying random data past the end of your original string, that could overflow into protected data that you don't have access to and throw a segfault(Inaccessible memory exception)

Answer (score 2):

According to strncpy() description here [1](https://clc-wiki.net/wiki/strncpy), the copy is done up to the length you provided, for null terminated string, so that when end of the string come before, like in this case, copy is done up to it and no more copy is done, so rest of the "123 bytes" are not copied, and the copy loop terminates

Answer (score 2):

The other answers to this question have addressed what happens with `strncpy()` (i.e. it will copy your string correctly because it stops at the 0-terminator byte), so perhaps what gets more to the intent of the question would be, what if you had this instead?

```
memcpy(my_buffer, my_string.c_str(), 128);
```

In this case, the function (`memcpy()`) doesn't know about 0-terminated-string semantics, and will always just blindly copy 128 bytes (starting at the address returned by `my_string.c_str()`) to the address `my_buffer`.  The first 6 (or so) of those bytes will be from `my_string`'s internal buffer, and the remaining bytes will be from whatever happens to be in memory after that.

So the question is, what happens then?  Well, this `memcpy()` call reads from "mystery memory" whose purpose you're not aware of, so you're invoking undefined behavior by doing that, and therefore in principle anything could happen.  In practice, the likely result is that your buffer will contain a copy of whatever bytes were read (although you probably won't notice them, since you'll be using string functions that don't look past the 0/terminator byte in your array anyway).

There is a small chance, though, that the "extra" memory bytes that `memcpy()` read could be part of a memory-page that is marked as off-limits, in which case trying to read from that page would likely cause a segmentation fault.

And finally, there's the real bugaboo of undefined behavior, which is that your C++ compiler's optimizer is allowed to do all kinds of crazy modifications to your code's logic, in the name of making your program more efficient -- and (assuming the optimizer isn't buggy) all of those optimizations will still result in the program running as intended -- *as long as the program follows the rules and doesn't invoke undefined behavior*.  Which is to say, if your program invokes undefined behavior in any way, the optimizations may be applied in ways that are [very difficult to predict or understand](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7entxbQOCc&index=34&list=PLHTh1InhhwT7J5jl4vAhO1WvGHUUFgUQH), resulting in bizarre/unexpected behavior in your program.  So the general rule is, *avoid undefined behavior like the plague*, because even if you think it "should be harmless", there's a very real possibility that it will end up doing things you wouldn't expect it to do, and then you're in for a long, painful debugging session as you try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: You answered the question which was not asked.

Comment: The question that *was* asked was (per the title): "what happens if strncpy() copies random data into a buffer?", to which the practical answer ("strncpy() won't do that, at least not in the example code you posted") is good info, but it doesn't answer the "what happens if" part.

Answer (score 0):

Function `strncpy` will copy everything up to NUL character or specified `size`. That's it.

In addition to other answers please remember that `strncpy` does not NUL terminate the `dst` buffer when the `src` string length (excluding NUL) is equal to buffer's `size` given. You should always do something like `my_buffer[127]=0` to prevent buffer overruns when handling the string later on. In `libbsd` there is `strlcpy` defined that always NUL terminate the buffer.

Check out this snippet:

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char buf[8];
    char *str = "deadbeef";

    strlcpy(buf, str, sizeof(buf));
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    strncpy(buf, str, sizeof(buf));
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

To see the problem compile it with flag `-fsanitize=address`. The second buffer is not NUL terminated!